# PHP Array is nesting into itself

Tags: php

I am having an issue with my array.

My output displays as:

```
 <article id="tab1"> 
 <figure>
 <img src="http://cdn.resize.flexmls.com/ric/640x480/true/20140820133948567093000000-o.jpg" > 
<article id="tab2"> 
 <figure>
 <img src="http://cdn.resize.flexmls.com/ric/640x480/true/20140820133948862522000000-o.jpg" >
```

I can't get the tag to close...

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$photos = $rets->GetObject("Property", "640x480", $row["field_Value"], "*", 1);
foreach ($photos as $photo) {
    $listing = $photo['Content-ID'];
    $number = $photo['Object-ID'];
    $location = $photo['Location'];

    if ($photo['Success'] == true) {
        // display on page
        echo "<article id=\"tab$number\"> \n <figure>\n <img src=\"{$photo['Location']}\" > \n";
    } else {
        echo "({$listing}-{$number}): {$photo['ReplyCode']} = {$photo['ReplyText']}\n";
    }
}
?>   

<article id="tab<?=$number?>">
    <figure>
        <img src="<?=$location?>" alt="Photo" width="586" height="402" />
    </figure>
```

Comment: Can you show your intended output (instead of describing it)?

Comment: I've updated it. I was able to remove the nesting, but I can't get each tag to close as you can see in my example.

Comment: Ok I updated this: echo "<article id=\"tab$number\"> <figure> <img src=\"{$photo['Location']}\" ></img></figure></article> \n"; and that seemed to place them in the correct hierarchy, but not it is diplaying as a list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How come you can't just close it in the echo part like you have for the beginning of it?

```
<?php
    $photos = $rets->GetObject("Property", "640x480", $row["field_Value"], "*", 1);
    foreach ($photos as $photo) {
            $listing    =   $photo['Content-ID'];
            $number     =   $photo['Object-ID'];
            $location   =   $photo['Location'];

            if ($photo['Success'] == true) { ?>
                <article id="tab<?php echo $number; ?>">
                    <figure>
                        <img src="<?php echo "{$photo['Location']}"; ?>" >
                    </figure>
                </article>
                <?php 
                }
            else 
                echo "({$listing}-{$number}): {$photo['ReplyCode']} = {$photo['ReplyText']}\n";
        } ?>
```

Comment: Ok great, your last comment had me thinking I was not picking up what you were putting down!! :D

Answer (score 0):

If I fully understand what your intent is, you just need to close the tags in that initial if statement.  So the code would look like this

```
<?php
$photos = $rets->GetObject("Property", "640x480", $row["field_Value"], "*", 1);
foreach ($photos as $photo) {
    $listing = $photo['Content-ID'];
    $number = $photo['Object-ID'];
    $location = $photo['Location'];

    if ($photo['Success'] == true) {
        // display on page
        echo "<article id=\"tab$number\"> \n <figure>\n <img src=\"{$photo['Location']}\" > \n";
        echo "</figure> \n";
        echo "</article> \n";
    } else {
        echo "({$listing}-{$number}): {$photo['ReplyCode']} = {$photo['ReplyText']}\n";
    }
?>
```